# Is there are way to foreach on object which class implements Iterator in PHP?

Tags: php, iterator

I tried to modify example from php.net for trying to implement Java/C#-like collection where keys may be objects (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php, Example # 2):

```
<?php
class Test {
        private $_n;
        public function __construct($n) {
              $this->_n = $n;  
        }
        public function getN() {
                return $this->_n;
        }
}
class MyIterator implements Iterator
{
    private $var = array();

   // code from php.net ....

    public function key() 
    {
        $var = key($this->var);
        echo "key: $var\n";

        return new Test($var);
    }

    // code from php.net...

}

$values = array(1,2,3);
$it = new MyIterator($values);

foreach ($it as $a => $b) {
    print $a->getN() . ": $b\n";
}
```

But I have notices like that:

> Warning: Illegal type returned from MyIterator::key()

How can I to fix it?

Comment: When you refer to a resource, could you at least post the URL?

Comment: PHP 5.5 will be the first PHP release that allows keys that are neither integer nor string. Documentation: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/foreach-non-scalar-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the key *must* be a scalar. The error is caused because your `key` method is returning an object. Return either a string or a numeric type and it should work.

Comment: My question was **HOW** to return an object.

Comment: The answer to that is "not in the `key()`"

Comment: C# and Java can iterate over collection where keys are objects. How to do it in PHP?

Comment: @GuyFawkes You can't, that it's that simple. The only thing you could do is to serialise the object to a string and use that as a key, but you'd be better of rethinking your strategy. The fact that C# and Java can do it, doesn't mean PHP has to.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You can return arrays and object as keys, the usage with `foreach` *is* limited, but it's easily feasible to deal with it, [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10689175/367456).

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is easy to do, however, you need to help `foreach` a little:

```
foreach ($it as $b) {
    $a = $it->key();
    print $a->getN() . ": $b\n";
}
```

Background: `foreach` can only deal with keys that are integer or string (some say scalar, I prefer the array key analogy), but not arrays or objects.

Manually getting the key however does work without problems and is sometimes even necessary with PHP built-in classes that are iterators but return an array as key, [for example with `MultipleIterator`](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/iterating-over-multiple-iterators-at-once/).

Comment: Yes, I already did this as workaround, but I'm very sad full realization is impossible in PHP

Comment: Oh my dear little, I can feel with you. But PHP is not a cozy langauge, if you need something that is more excellent in syntax and usage, I highly recommend scala.

Answer (score 0):

`key()` should return the position, not the element at that position. If we imagine we are in array-world, let's say: return the key, not the value.

The manual on [`key()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/iterator.key.php) says:

> Returns the key of the current element.
>
> Returns scalar on success, or NULL on failure.

If you want to return an element at the current position, please use [`current()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/iterator.current.php):

> Returns the current element.
>
> Can return any type.

**UPDATE:** You cannot use an object as key unfortunately.

Comment: I want to return not element at position (for example, for index === 0, it will be 1), but an object.

Comment: @GuyFawkes You don't want to do that in `key()`. Read the manual. What you need is `current()`.

Comment: current is not what I need. Read the question. I need to implement C#-like collection where keys can be objects.

Comment: @GuyFawkes You never mentioned this in your question. If you had done so, I would have already told you that you cannot do it. Please edit your question.

Comment: I edit question. It's very bad that PHP cannot into object keys.

Answer (score 0):

Another work-around: Have current return an array with your key and value...

```
function current() {
    return array($this->key, $this->val);
}
```

...and then unpack the array in your loops:

```
foreach ($iterator as $key_and_value) {
    list($key, $value) = $key_and_value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP 5.5 or later, it will work:

> **foreach now supports non-scalar keys**
>
> foreach now supports keys of any type. While non-scalar keys cannot
>   occur in native PHP arrays, it is possible for `Iterator::key()` to
>   return a value of any type, and this will now be handled correctly.

http://php.net/manual/de/migration55.new-features.php